# Delete file/folder containing special character

Tags: unix, ftp

I tried to create folder `/parent/child` by sending a FTP command but I made a mistake to write `\parent\child`

So on that Unix, it created file named **\parent\child** instead of **child** under **/parent** folder.

As soon as find it out, I've used many ways to delete that folder but nothing works :(

Please give me any suggest so I could try to delete it again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then type

```
rm \\parent\\child
```

and it should remove it, eg escape the character you need treated as litteral.

Comment: Thanks! I just find out can delete by quote it as well! Stupid me, don't try it :)

Comment: Ive seen plenty of files called "?" or "cd \" etc